# What is the equivalent in .Net of the :print: character class from PHP or Java?

Tags: java, php, .net, regex

I have some validators that in Java and PHP that are using this :print: character class in their regexes to validate input lengths. Any human readable input is valid as long as it doesn't exceed a limit.

In the .Net part we are using the *word* (\w) characters class. This lead to a bug where lots of characters weren't matched by the .Net regex (ie. #, currencies, so on).

The question is: is **\s\S** a valid equivalent for **:print:**? If not what are the other options I have?

Comment: Would using \P{C} work? It would allow all except any control characters since I assume everything else would be "printable characters"?

Comment: Do you use the `/u` modifier in PHP and `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` in Java?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I don't

Comment: Ok, I have found a post that should provide enough answers. In your case, you can use `[ -~]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: \P{Cc} what what I needed